# Calculating changes in NDVI in time using Landsat 7 image and Landsat 8 image

Tags: raster-calculator, ndvi, landsat-8, landsat-7

I'm trying to understand how much urban vegetation has changed in the past 20 years in my city. The plan is to calculate NDVI for Time1 and NDVI for Time2 and subtract them.

BUT Landsat 7 images, that cover my desired time frame (2001-2021), have a missing strip of data since 2003.

Can I use a Landsat 7 image for Time1 (2001) and a Landsat 8 image for Time2 (2021) to calculate changes in NDVI?

Or are there significant differences between both sensors?

Is this methodologically sound?